# Putting a fixed element behind another fixed element

Tags: html, css, sass

I got 2 divs, I'm tying to put one of them behind the other one, which means the wrapper should slice the low level div and be above it.

I tried using the z-index property but it didn't help

```css
  
    .feedback-wrapper {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 300px;
    background-color: #fff;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 999;
    bottom: 25%;
    top: 25%;
    left: -310px;
   ...
    .arrow-wrapper {
      transition: 0.2s;
      position: fixed;
      top: 40%;
      left: -0.5rem;
      // background-color: red;
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      z-index: 1;

      i {
        &:first-of-type {
          position: relative;
          font-size: 25rem;
          font-weight: bold;
          color: rgba(38, 156, 117, 0.6);
        }

        &:nth-child(2) {
          cursor: pointer;
          position: absolute;
          top: 116px;
          left: 55px;
          font-size: 2rem;
          color: #fff;
          font-weight: bold;
        }
      }

    }
     }
```

```html
        <div class="feedback-wrapper"> 
         ...
            </div>

            <div class="arrow-wrapper">
            <i class="fas fa-chevron-right" id="arrow-feedback" ></i>
         <i class="fas fa-question" id="toggle-feedback"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
```

the result should be so the wrapper cuts the green arrow and go above it like in the image below:
[image]
thanks a lot!

Comment: Your example does not show anything at all. There seems to be some part of the HTML code missing

Comment: z-index will work only when if they are applied on the divs or elements on the same level. In your case, one element is a parent & another is a child.

Comment: You do not necessarily have to use z-index for this, you could also just make sure that the element containing the arrow is on the same level within the DOM as the window (modal) and rendered before rather than after.